# What are Bot Session in Microsoft Clarity and how can I identify a session is a bot session. Can we prevent a bot session?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, ms-clarity

I have recently integrated **Microsoft Clarity** into our website and have encountered an issue with the **'Total sessions'** data on my dashboard, which includes **'bot sessions.'** Despite conducting thorough research, I have been unable to find specific information regarding these bot sessions within the Clarity platform. As a result, I am seeking a comprehensive understanding of what these bot sessions represent in Clarity, how they are generated, their potential impact on our website, strategies for accessing detailed information about these sessions, and effective approaches for monitoring and tracking their increasing count.

Additionally, **I am interested in determining whether these bot sessions were generated using automation tools such as Selenium or similar methods.** Were these sessions used by users for web scraping purposes? Furthermore, **any guidance on where to find documentation related to this matter would be greatly appreciated.** I tried the documentation of the Microsoft Clarity there is no mention of such session.

I've reviewed the documentation thoroughly and posted my question in the Q&A section on the Microsoft website.